# Blow up of a subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

I have a problem understanding blowing up a subvariety. I've had some experience blowing up singular points on curves. I suppose the best way to address the question is to pose an example. Take the equation

$f(x,y,z,w)=(x-y)(z-w)$, and $\nabla f=0$ on the subvariety $x-y=0$, $z-w=0$.

My question is how do I blow up these singular lines? If you could possibly direct me to a resource or give an explanation that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about which lines you mean. But anyway, a great resource for learning about blowups (in scheme language) is "Geometry of Schemes" by Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: Your question is related to this older question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240301/blowing-up-at-a-subvariety/875204#875204 and I think the answer there will be useful for you as well.